# Is it possible to do The Pitt without a slave outfit?

Tags: fallout-3

I found the slave camp before I found The Pitt guy. I killed the slavers, freed the slaves, talked to The Pitt guy and didn't choose the right dialog options. Then went back to Megaton to do a whole lot of other things before returning to The Pitt guy, and only by now did I found out that I did choose the wrong dialog options. So, I need a slave outfit.

Problem is, I went there around level 11, I'm 25 by now. I don't have a save game from then nor do I intend to start the game all over again.

How can I still aquire a slave outfit? Or is it impossible now to play this quest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step one is to return to the [train tunnel,](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Train_tunnel_(Fallout_3)) which is near the north end of the map, northwest of Fort Constantine and a distance east of Raven Rock.

If you didn't take it and sell it, there's a slave outfit in the slave pen here, on a dead slave.  It doesn't sound like you did this, but you might have and then didn't mention it in your question.

If you can't find a slave outfit, you should try entering the train tunnel anyhow - the quest page for [Into the Pitt](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Into_The_Pitt) says that Werhner will take you to the Pitt even if you opt not to take a disguise.

I myself abandoned the disguise early on, and the DLC plays out roughly the same in this case.

Comment: I did try this before, no luck. Now THE slave was here again. Maby Some bug orso. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I read [on the Fallout Wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Prosper#Notes) that Prosper will likely end up at the entrance to Vault 101, and you can get his clothes through dialog. I tested this as I did the same thing as you, and it worked.